# A system error occurred: uv_os_get_passwd returned ENOENT (no such file or directory)

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a jenkin pipeline that it runs on a docker agent when I run ember build I get this error.
Any idea what should I do . I use

```
image 'node:latest'
```

and I get this error

```
+ ./node_modules/.bin/ember build --env production
WARNING: Node v14.3.0 is not tested against Ember CLI on your platform. We recommend that you use the most-recent "Active LTS" version of Node.js. See https://git.io/v7S5n for details.
Could not start watchman
Visit https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
Building
A system error occurred: uv_os_get_passwd returned ENOENT (no such file or directory)
```

Comment: Try using `image 'node:12'` ?

Comment: @Gaurav unfortunately I am still getting the same error .

Comment: If I get [this issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/8054) right, it sounds like being related to the way how Jenkins invokes the docker image. I would try to understand how Jenkins invokes the docker image and then see if I can reproduce it without Jenkins. Afterwards you hopefully have an idea what you need to change in Jenkins or the CI pipeline to work-a-round this issue. At least it will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it turned out all I needed to do was adding docker volumne mapping from /etc/passwd to /etc/passwd. like this :

```
agent {
        docker { 
            image 'node:12'
            args "-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd"
            reuseNode true
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue could be masking another issue with a missing or readonly path when using `node-gyp` in containers.

The `os.userInfo()` usage is part of the [eaccesFallback](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/4937722cf597ccd1953628f3d5e2ab5204280051/lib/install.js#L374) which should only be called if a file path cannot be accessed.

Switch on verbose logging (`npm_config_loglevel=verbose`) to log the path which cannot be accessed and mount/fix that instead.

In my experience, this fixed the underlying issue and avoided mounting `/etc/passwd` which may not always be possible or could be considered insecure.

I specifically saw this in k8s pods when using `electron-builder` and had to create an empty volume mount for the `.electron-gyp` folder:

```
  volumeMounts:
  - name: electron-cache
    mountPath: /.electron-gyp
  volumes:
  - name: electron-cache
    emptyDir: {}
```